# hotchocolate custom filter on parent based on child collection

Tags: c#, graphql, hotchocolate

I'm trying to implement similar to [described here](https://grandstack.io/docs/graphql-filtering.html#nested-filter) filtering model with [hotchocolate](https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate) code-first approach. I need to filter movies if at least one of their actors meets certain criteria. Model looks like this:

```
public class Movie
{
    public IList<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
}

public class Actor { }

public class MovieTypeDef : ObjectType<Movie>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Movie> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Field(x => x.Actors)
            .Type<NonNullType<ListType<NonNullType<ActorTypeDef>>>>();
    }
}

public class ActorTypeDef : ObjectType<Actor> { }

public class Query
{
    public IList<Movie> Movies()
    {
        return new List<Movie>();
    }
}

public class QueryTypeDef : ObjectType<Query>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Query> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Field(x => x.Movies())
            .Type<NonNullType<ListType<MovieTypeDef>>>()
            .UseFiltering<MoviesFileringTypeDef>();
    }
}

public class MoviesFileringTypeDef : FilterInputType<Movie>
{
    protected override void Configure(IFilterInputTypeDescriptor<Movie> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Filter(x => x.Actors) // compilation error
    }
}
```

There seems to be no ability to add custom filter to `MoviesFileringTypeDef` since it only allows using properties of `Movie` class, and collections are not accepted there. 
Is it possible to implement such filter with hotchocolate?

Comment: If you implement a custom query rewriter it should be possible.

Comment: Is there any update on this one? I am running into similar scenario. It would be helpful if there is a way to tackle this.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced a similar kind of issue while I was trying to apply a filter on the parent entity based on the child entity field. I believe in your case you need to apply a filter in your MovieTypeDef also with QueryType as below:

```
public class MovieTypeDef : ObjectType<Movie>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Movie> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Field(x => x.Actors)
            .Type<NonNullType<ListType<NonNullType<ActorTypeDef>>>>()
            .UseFiltering<YourModel>();
    }
}
```

After this change, you can apply a filter on a nested level also as you can apply with the parent level.